# XSLT 2.0 - How to find unmatched references/pairs

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML documents that contain many elements that reference other elements by id/ref pairs, similar to the example shown below. I just need to identify if there are any references that do not match any existing ids. I thought this would be straightforward, but if it is, I'm missing the trick to it.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
  <Person id="abc">
    <Name>David</Name>
  </Person>
  <Person id="def">
    <Name>Mark</Name>
  </Person>
  <Person id="ghi">
    <Name>James</Name>
  </Person>
  <Nickname ref="ghi">
    <Nname>Jim</Nname>
  </Nickname>
  <Nickname ref="abc">
    <Nname>Dave</Nname>
  </Nickname>
  <Nickname ref="xyz">
    <Nname>Fred</Nname>
  </Nickname>
  <Document id="123">
    <DocName>Document 1</DocName>
  </Document>
  <Document id="456">
    <DocName>Document 2</DocName>
  </Document>
  <Chapter ref="123">
    <Cname>Chapter 1</Cname>
  </Chapter>
  <Chapter ref="999">
    <Cname>Chapter 999</Cname>
  </Chapter>
</Root>
```

In this example, I would want the output to return the Nickname reference xyz and the Chapter reference 999, because those do not match anything in the XML document. I do NOT need or want it to return any information about the unmatched Person or Document. I've tried about 20 variations on ways of comparing sequences, but I must be missing something because I can't get the result I need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rather simple way you could use:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="elem-by-id" match="*" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <unmatched-references>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[@ref][not(key('elem-by-id', @ref))]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@ref"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </unmatched-references>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result of processing your input example will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<unmatched-references>
  <Nickname ref="xyz"/>
  <Chapter ref="999"/>
</unmatched-references>
```

---

### Added in response to comments:

As there seems to be some misconception about the role of `xsl:for-each` in the above example, let me me show another one:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="elem-by-id" match="*" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:variable name="unmatched-referring-elements" select="*[@ref][not(key('elem-by-id', @ref))]"/>
    <unmatched-references>
        <xsl:value-of select="$unmatched-referring-elements/@ref" separator=", "/>
    </unmatched-references>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<unmatched-references>xyz, 999</unmatched-references>
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I was really hoping for a 2.0 solution. I would think that 2.0 should have something quicker/more elegant than the relatively slow For-Each loop.

Comment: I'm curious, why use a key?  Another approach would be, in the `for-each` element, a `select` statement of `//*[@ref][not(@ref = //*/@id)]`, and omit the `<xsl:key>` altogether.  I see no noticeable difference -- both complete with a stated debug execution time of 0.0s.  But then again this is a very small file.  Are keys more efficient in larger datasets?

Comment: @DaveInAZ 1. I am not aware of `xsl:for-each` being "relatively slow". Relative to what? 2. I would probably not do anything different in XSLT 2.0, but that depends on the exact expected result - which is missing from your question.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi This is a problem in resolving cross-references - and keys are XSLT's designated tool for resolving cross-references. They are supposed to be more efficient due to pre-indexing, but actual performance is processor-dependent.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - I don't want to seem ungrateful. I do appreciate your help. I hope that's clear. To answer your question, I would expect set-based operations, such as doing a Difference on two Sequences (which is what I was attempting) to be considerably faster than looping through hundreds of IDs for each Ref, of which there will also be at least dozens, if not hundreds. I was under the impression that such improvements were the reason for introducing all the new functionality to XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @DaveInAZ **1.** Please edit your question and post the exact code you expect to get as the result. **2.** `xsl:for-each` is not a loop. Nevertheless, I don't see how this task can be accomplished without examining each individual reference. Calling it a "set operation" is just a programming convenience; someone has to actually perform it - and that means checking each member of set A against each member of set B (or, as in this case, against the index of set B).

Comment: @DaveInAZ **3.** Keep in mind that the ids and refs are two completely different sets, with no common member. IOW, a value is not a node.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - 1. unnecessary. The format of the result is unimportant. Your demonstrated output is fine. 2. XSL did not invent the For-Each concept, and it has always been a loop. If you choose to call it something else, that doesn't change anything. For-Each execution is commonly referred to as "looping through the defined set". 3. On the contrary, MOST of the members of each set (IDs and Refs) are members of BOTH sets, because the members are not the nodes or the attributes, but the VALUES. And the values are simply strings that either are, or are not, identical.

Comment: @DaveInAZ You seem to know much more about this than I do, so I am not sure why you would need me to help you. On the contrary: if you know a way to output an element for each member of a sequence without doing either `xsl:for-each` or `xsl:apply-templates`, I would love to learn it.

Comment: I found this on another site, "XPath only allows set operations over sequences of nodes. Atomic values are not allowed. This is because the set operations are over node identity and not value." That would explain why my set-based approach didn't work (assuming this is correct).

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment, I found this on another site, *"XPath only allows set operations over sequences of nodes. Atomic values are not allowed. This is because the set operations are over node identity and not value."* I'm repeating it here for people who may see this page, but not read all the comments.

That means my initial set-based approach would never work, because the sets I wanted to use were composed of values, not nodes. So I switched to a template-based approach, using a key.

So, I am using a key, like this;

`<xsl:key name="elem-by-id" match="*" use="@id" />`

Along with that key, I created a template that works the same way as Michael's variable. This limits processing to those elements that have an @ref that does not match any @id in the XML document. 
`<xsl:template match="//*[@ref][not(key('elem-by-id', @ref))]">`

That gets the elements that contain the unmatched @ref attributes, directly. Then, inside the template, I can just get the value of the unmatched @ref with a very simple select.

`<xsl:value-of select="@ref"/>`

I chose to go with this approach because it lets me also easily retrieve the name of the element that contains the unmatched @ref.

`<xsl:value-of select="./../name()">`

Comment: I am not sure what advantage your approach has over my suggestion. You should be aware that having a template that matches some elements does **not** "*limit processing to those elements*". If you do not have other templates that either process them or prevent them from being processed, the unmatched elements will be handled by the built-in template rules, which may cause unintended results. -- Note also that  a `//` at the beginning of a match pattern does not do anything,